# how to access class variables and constants in annotation in symfony 2 php

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a class like this:

```
class Student {

const GENDER_MALE = "male", GENDER_FEMALE = "female";
/**
 * @var string $gender
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", length=50,nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Gender cannot be blank",groups={"new"})
 * @Assert\Choice(choices = {"male", "female"}, message = "Choose a valid gender.", groups={"new"})
 */
private $gender;
```

I have to hard code the values `"male"` and `"female"`. Is it possible to do something like this ?

> choices = {self::GENDER_MALE, self::GENDER_FEMALE}

Comment: Use `callback` option instead, and in method you can return array of your constants.

Comment: looks like a good alternative. thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is a feature of [Doctrine2 Annotation Reader (Constants)](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/current/custom.html#constants).

You solution:

```
class Student
{
    const GENDER_MALE = "male", GENDER_FEMALE = "female";

    /**
     * @var string $gender
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", length=50,nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Gender cannot be blank",groups={"new"})
     * @Assert\Choice(
     *      choices = {
     *          Student::GENDER_FEMALE: "Female",
     *          Student::GENDER_MALE: "Male"
     *      },
     *      message = "Choose a valid gender.", groups={"new"}
     * )
     */
    private $gender;
}
```

Comment: In your example it should be noted that you need to add the use statement if you link to other classes.

Comment: Have you tried your example @ZhukV? I just tried a use statement and an external class and unfortunately the constants are not used. Maybe the Doctrine annotations won't work with @Assert?

It seems to work with Expressions though:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34479472/1937050

Comment: @webDEVILopers, please not merge doctrine annotation and symfony expression language. These components have difference logic and processes for read/process annotation. Doctrine annotation only read annotation from method/property/class AND ONLY! Symfony constraints can work with any logic with constraint system.

Comment: Thanks @ZhukV! Indeed the following version works: https://gist.github.com/webdevilopers/e071d40d6d0a573f8ef8ac8e78975dc9#gistcomment-1937091

Comment: i'm trying to use assert\choice with multiple=false and expanded=false as i use them in a normal FormType.. multiple is working fine but expanded throws an exception, i checked the documentation and there's no expanded option.. any idea if i'm missing something?

Comment: What is `,groups={"new"}` about?

Comment: @Trix groups={"new"} refers to validation group

Comment: I'm getting `Couldn't find constant default` whatever the constant I use here