# Symfony2 Assert\Expression annotation doesn't support Constants

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, metaprogramming

Generally I use `Constants` in all of annotation based places e.g. `annotations, route and assert annotations`, but in Assert\Expression it throws `Variable "EntityInterface" is not valid around position 26.`
Is this a bug or is a special rare case ?

```
<?php

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_number", type="string", length=11, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Expression(
     *     "this.getNationality() == EntityInterface::COUNTRY_DEFAULT_VALUE and value != null",
     *     message = "form.user.validation.id_number.blank",
     *     groups = {"personal_info"}
     * )
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *      pattern="/^([\d]{11})$/",
     *      match=true,
     *      message="form.user.validation.id_number.regex",
     *      groups = {"personal_info"}
     * )
     */
    private $idNumber;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_number", type="string", length=11, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this.getNationality() == constant('EntityInterface::COUNTRY_DEFAULT_VALUE') and value != null",
 *     message = "form.user.validation.id_number.blank",
 *     groups = {"personal_info"}
 * )
 */
```

instead (omitted parts of your example to focus on using `constant()` here).

For reference, see

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html#working-with-functions
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

Comment: It doesn't work, It says `Warning: constant(): Couldn't find constant EntityInterface::COUNTRY_DEFAULT_VALUE` I checked constant is there.

Comment: OK I find the problem in this way it needs namespace sorry. FrontendBundle\\EntityInterface::COUNTRY_DEFAULT_VALUE it is OK now.

Comment: Indeed @FZE it looks like the constant function() can not read from use statements and needs escaping:

@Assert\Expression("!(this.foo == constant('App\\Domain\\Bundle\\Foo\\Foo::bar)")


Unlike other Constraints like Range for instance:

use AppDomain\Model\Foo\Foo;
@Assert\Range(min=Foo::MIN_NUMBER)