# Symfony Validator error code from consts

Tags: symfony

I'm using annotations for validation, and for adding error code I'm using the payload option, something like this :

```
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *      message = "required.value",
 *      payload=102000
 * )
```

Now I have the requirement to create a class with consts or static fields, like `ValidationErrors::REQUIRED_VALUE`, and use it inside annotations like so :

```
 * @Assert\NotBlank(
 *      message = "required.value",
 *      payload=ValidationErrors::REQUIRED_VALUE
 * )
```

So my question is, is it possible ? without any callback ?

Comment: not with annotation. You can try with yml/xml syntax definition

Comment: So, the doctrine annotation supports constants, and all good works. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670117/how-to-access-class-variables-and-constants-in-annotation-in-symfony-2-php/30680267#30680267