# How to set variable in doctrine anotation?

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, doctrine

I'm wondering how if it's possible, to inject variable into my doctrine anotation :

```
<?php
/**
* @Entity
* @Table(name="ecommerce_products")
*/
class ECommerceProduct
{
}
```

Assuming ecommerce_products is a variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670117/how-to-access-class-variables-and-constants-in-annotation-in-symfony-2-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to access class variables and constants in annotation in symfony 2 php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670117/how-to-access-class-variables-and-constants-in-annotation-in-symfony-2-php)

Comment: Not duplicate. These 2 questions was about totally different situation.

Could you please tell us, why you need to achieve this, what's your goal?

Comment: I'm building a symfony blog admin bundle.
And for multisite hosted purpose on single database, i need to prefix tables.
I wouldnt like to edit the bundle entities files for each new project.
I'm thinking of just set it for example into the .env file

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this is a recommended troubleshooting but it's fixed the issue.
I use a constant as follow:

```
<?php

 ...

define('ProductsTable', 'ecommerce_products')

/**
* @Entity
* @Table(name=ProductsTable)
*/
class ECommerceProduct
{
}
```

Notice the **absence** of quotes. Thus symfony consideres it as a constant. What give us lot of ways to set it from anywhere outside.